# como leer XML en Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hola buenas espero que me puedan colaborar.

estoy tratando de leer un xml que lo coloque en una variable logre leer campo 1 con la siguiente instrucción

```
set @alxml = @valor.value('(/root/DI1/element/ts)[1]','varchar(100)')
```

pero cuando deseo cambiar el [1], por una variable que se autoincremente por contador que la estoy colocando de esta manera:

```
set @alxml = @valor.value('(/root/DI1/element/ts)['+ convert(varchar(3),@mcon)+']','varchar(100)')
```

me da este mensaje: ***The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.***

si me pueden colaborar se lo agradecería, esto es para llevar una tabla.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si imprimes el valor de "set @alxml = @valor.value('(/root/DI1/element/ts)[1]','varchar(100)')" , que obtienes?

Comment: cuando la ejecuto me da el valor correcto, pero no puedo colocarle [1], ya que el xml puede variar por el nro de fila

Comment: Veo que cambiaste de estrategia. En lugar de leer json, quieres enviar un xml. Parece más un problema de X->Y. No estoy seguro si es el caso, pero me atrevo a decir que el problema original X tiene una solución en tu capa de negocios. Qué es lo que quieres lograr? Enviar una lista de objetos a la base de datos y luego guardarlos?

Answer (score 0):

Tal cual lo planteas, me da la impresión de que no es posible.

No obstante hay varias soluciones. Una posible, es el uso de sql dinámico.

```
declare @valor xml ='<root>
    <DI1>
        <element>
            <ts>
            value1
            </ts>
            <ts>
            value2
            </ts>
            <ts>
            value3
            </ts>
        </element>
    </DI1>
</root>'

declare @alxml varchar(1090)
declare @i int=2;
declare @literal varchar(1024)=Concat('(/root/DI1/element/ts)[',@i,']')
declare @return varchar(100);
Declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(max)= 'Select @salida=@x.value('''+ @literal +''',''varchar(100)'')';


exec sp_executeSql @sqlQuery, @parameters = N'@x xml, @salida varchar(100) output',@x = @valor, @salida = @return output;
select @return
```

En la variable @i, indicas el valor a escoger.

[image: Res]

Con eso tienes en la variable @return lo que contiene la ejecución.

Tienes otras posibilidades en este hilo del sitio en inglés.

[Xml Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397722/the-argument-1-of-the-xml-data-type-method-value-must-be-a-string-literal)

Siempre hay que tener en cuenta que cuando usas código dinámico, por seguridad, la cadena no puede estár accesible a datos que introduzca el usuario directamente para no tener Sql Inyection.

[Sql dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/02/03/sql-dinamico-como-se-hace/)

Comment: Muchas Gracias hare la prueba asi.